# IF statement to return different values for 3+ conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, logic

I'm trying to configure a volume discount system in a cell. I want to say:

> If qty is 1, cost is $49.99; if qty is 2-3, cost is $49.50; if qty is 4+, cost is $48.99.

The furthest I've gotten is:

```
=OR((IF(I7<2,49.99)),(IF(OR(I7>1,I7<4),49.5)))
```

in which `I7` is the cell containing qty. This returns `TRUE` which I understand is how the `OR` function works.

I'm just at a loss to how I can incorporate multiple outputs into a single cell given multiple potential conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can omit `OR` and simply chain multiple `IF`s:

```
=IF(I7<=0, 0, IF(I7=1, 49.99, IF(I7<4, 49.5, 48.99)))
```

In pseudo-code, this reads:

```
If      I7 <= 0, then return  0.00
else If I7 =  1, then return 49.99
else If I7 <  4, then return 49.50
else                  return 48.99
```

Comment: Ok I'd tried nested IF's before, but I guess I'd made a mistake so thanks.

But I want to be more specific. With your formula, values in `I7` that are =-0 return `49.50`. Here's my adjusted formula, but for values 2 and 3, it returns 0...

`=IF(I7=1, 49.99, IF(1<I7<4, 49.5, IF(I7>3, 48.99, 0)))`

Comment: You can't use `1<I7<4` to check for "between."  You'd need to do `AND(1 < I7, I7 < 4)`.  See my update, which now adds the `0` case.

Comment: Ok thanks. I used the `AND` formula for handling negative numbers as well.

Comment: In that case, the first test should be `I7<=0`.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that's less clutter :)

Answer (score 1):

A conventional alternative to nested IFs is to use a sorted lookup_array for breakpoints only and apply [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) with the inexact match option. Say you have a range (if of Workbook Scope, anywhere in the workbook) named `table_array`:

```
| 1 | 49.99 |  
| 2 | 49.5  |  
| 4 | 48.99 |
```

and E1 contains the quantity:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,table_array,2,1)
```

Comment: I actually thought about using `VLOOKUP` but my data wasn't sorted. I didn't think about having a separate table of values off to the side though. Thanks for the extra input!